# Android Gradle 2.5 how to get resConfigs to work

Tags: android, gradle, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin

To use the latest NDK support in Android Studio you have to use Gradle 2.5. 
http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/gradle-experimental

Which introduces a new syntax. eg.  buildToolsVersion "23.0.1" becomes  buildToolsVersion = "23.0.1"

For resConfigs pre Gradle 2.5 you write it:

```
 defaultConfig {
        ...
        resConfigs "en", "fr"
        }
```

But with 2.5, I could not find a way to write a comma delimited strings.

Even when I tried with one string

```
defaultConfig.with  {
        ...
        resConfigs = "fr"
        }
```

I got this error 
**Error:No such property: resConfigs for class: com.android.build.gradle.managed.ProductFlavor**

I need this as AppCompat has translations for many languages which I am not supporting ATM.

**Edit Updates**
I figured how to enter a list of strings in the new format e.g

```
resConfigs = ["fr", "es"]
```

### But still I get the error of it not recognising resConfigs

when running with **./gradlew  --stacktrace assembleDebug** here is the output

```
 problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Exception thrown while executing model rule: model.android
   > No such property: resConfigs for class: com.android.build.gradle.managed.ProductFlavor

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.ProjectConfigurationException: A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
    at org.gradle.execution.TaskNameResolver.selfClosedTasksNode(TaskNameResolver.java:116)
    at org.gradle.execution.TaskNameResolver.hasTask(TaskNameResolver.java:128)
    at org.gradle.execution.TaskNameResolver.access$100(TaskNameResolver.java:38)
    at org.gradle.execution.TaskNameResolver$MultiProjectTaskSelectionResult.collect(TaskNameResolver.java:195)
    at org.gradle.execution.TaskNameResolver$MultiProjectTaskSelectionResult.collect(TaskNameResolver.java:203)
    at org.gradle.execution.TaskNameResolver$MultiProjectTaskSelectionResult.collectTasks(TaskNameResolver.java:191)
    at org.gradle.execution.TaskNameResolver.selectWithName(TaskNameResolver.java:61)
    at org.gradle.execution.TaskSelector.getSelection(TaskSelector.java:87)
    at org.gradle.execution.TaskSelector.getSelection(TaskSelector.java:75)
    at org.gradle.execution.commandline.CommandLineTaskParser.parseTasks(CommandLineTaskParser.java:42)
    at org.gradle.execution.TaskNameResolvingBuildConfigurationAction.configure(TaskNameResolvingBuildConfigurationAction.java:44)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:25)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:57)
    at org.gradle.execution.ExcludedTaskFilteringBuildConfigurationAction.configure(ExcludedTaskFilteringBuildConfigurationAction.java:47)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:51)
```

Comment: The 2.5 document says ***Most** properties require the = operator*, have you tried without the `=` ?

Comment: Yes I tried the old way and Gradle won't build as there is a syntax error

Comment: What version of `com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental` are you using?

Comment: can you please run with --stacktrace and post your stacktrace?

Comment: I have tried  'com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.2.0' and
        'com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.3.0-alpha5'

Comment: I have added output when using --stacktrace

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what works for me:

```
| gradle-experimental version   | Gradle version | resConfigs usage                  |
|-------------------------------|----------------|-----------------------------------|
| 0.2.0                         | 2.5            | resourceConfigurations = ["fr"]   |
| 0.3.0-alpha5                  | 2.6            | resourceConfigurations = ["fr"]   |
| 0.6.0-alpha5                  | 2.10           | resourceConfigurations << "fr"    |
```

---

The thing I don't get is, I looked up the source of `gradle-core-1.4.0-beta4` which is a dependency for `gradle-experimental:0.3.0-alpha5` and the DSL for productFlavor does contain code for `resConfig` and `resConfigs`. In `com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.ProductFlavor.java`

```
public void resConfigs(@NonNull String... config) {
    addResourceConfigurations(config);
}
```

I'm unsure why it isn't being picked up correctly.

Comment: The previous syntax doesn't work with gradle experimental  0.21

Comment: yes sorry I made a typo forgot to show I tried with  defaultConfig.with, as that was the only way to enter it in with the new structure

Comment: this gives the following error -  Error:(70, 0) Could not find property 'android' on task ':app:model'.

Comment: sweet thanks it worked so get an array of languages the solution was:
resourceConfigurations = ["fr", "es"]
, it would have been nice of Google to mention the change in Experiment tools documentation

Comment: also where did you find that the field used now is resourceConfigurations, in case I come across other terms like useLibrary which is not available in the experimental builds

Comment: You want to learn to fish eh? Since your error message complained that `resConfigs` doesn't exist in ProductFlavor.java, I looked for ProductFlavor.java source to see what properties it actually does have; and found `resourceConfigurations` and that it is of type `set<String>` and did a bit of trial-and-error from there. This is still alpha, so things could change btw and I'm sure they'll document it when they're done.

Answer (score 0):

For gradle dsl 7.2

```kotlin
resConfigs("pl", "en", "ru", "uk")
```